How to assign levels to categorical data without clearing out entries
I have this set of data
BF Condition              SampleID
1 Partially Formula Fed   VD25FE8997
 2 Exclusively Breast Fed  VD25FE8986
 3 Exclusively Breast Fed  VD25FE8974
 4 Exclusively Breast Fed  VD25FE8960
 5 Exclusively Formula Fed VD25FE8951

there are three 'levels' i would like to establish in order to run Chao1 Indexes using a boxplot
Exclusively Breast Fed, Partially for
When I pull up the levels, they appear as 'NULL'
# Convert 'category' to factor if it's not already
VitDSI_Data$BFCondition <- factor(VitDSI_Data$BFCondition)

# Add new levels to the 'category' factor
levelsToAdd <- c("Exclusively Breast Fed", "Partially Breast Fed", "Exclusively Formula Fed")
VitDSI_Data$BFCondition <- factor(VitDSI_Data$BFCondition, levels = c(levels(VitDSI_Data$BFCondition), levelsToAdd))

I tried this, but in turn it is clearing out the data in the environment. I am not sure how to assign the levels in order to get the following readout (shortened)
Is it that my 'levels' assignments are too long?
##  [1] Exclusively Breast Fed      Exclusively Formula Fed      Partially Formula Fed
   
## Levels: Exclusively Breast Fed      Exclusively Formula Fed      Partially Formula Fed


Either, don't use levels redundantly, or use union() instead of c().
> VitDSI_Data$BFCondition <- factor(VitDSI_Data$BFCondition, 
+                                   levels=union(levels(VitDSI_Data$BFCondition), 
+                                                levelsToAdd))
> levels(VitDSI_Data$BFCondition)
[1] "Exclusively Breast Fed"  "Exclusively Formula Fed" "Partially Formula Fed"  
[4] "Partially Breast Fed" 


Data:
> dput(VitDSI_Data)
structure(list(BFCondition = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Exclusively Breast Fed", 
"Exclusively Formula Fed", "Partially Formula Fed", "Partially Breast Fed"
), class = "factor"), SampleID = c("VD25FE8997", "VD25FE8986", 
"VD25FE8974", "VD25FE8960", "VD25FE8951")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(levelsToAdd)
c("Exclusively Breast Fed", "Partially Breast Fed", "Exclusively Formula Fed"
)

